# Particle objects are being skewed

Tags: particles

I'm attempting to add efficient stylized fur with physics to a character, and I currently think the best way would be using a single fur clump object and a particle system. I'm using the particle instance modifier with "create along paths" checked so it can bend. This worked fine when I was first testing it, but I've discovered that the fur clumps start to skew, flatten, and flip inside out upon adding the particle system to a more complicated mesh or setting the particle system's source from faces to vertices. Is there a way to stop the particles from breaking like this, or perhaps an alternative way to create the fur? The .blend file and pictures are from the latest version of Blender, but my main computer is stuck on 2.79b if that could affect anything. Thanks!

.blend file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1c7CB2S_gJliGU2KfZqYJX7qy8uMzQG_F/view?usp=sharing

Simplified fur clump:

[image: Particle object]

The simplified fur clump getting skewed:

[image: Particle getting skewed]